# Would any of the advanced Linux/UNIX filesystems be viable on Android?

Tags: file-system

I know ext4 is already used as an internal filesystem but I wondered if there would be anything gained by using something like btrfs or ZFS? I know they are meant for more server-oriented situations but I'm just curious if there are any features that might help on a flash memory based smartphone.

Comment: Neither ext4 nor btrfs or zfs are really usable on a flash filesystem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_file_system

Comment: I believe some of the filesystems I mentioned can be at least partially configured to work better with flash memory than they do by default.

Comment: ext4 even *is* used on Android devices. "really unusable" might be correct for older flash modules (say, two years ago), which was while things like e.g. YAFFS were used back then. With current chips, much of the corresponding logic previously handled by the file systems (wear leveling etc.) have been moved to the flash controller, so other file systems can very well be used here.

Comment: In fairness, trying to shoe-horn in btrfs or ZFS on Android when the more commonly accepted filesystems are ext[2|3|4]... just saying, have not heard of android running on anything else...